# Why is this simple word macro so slow

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

This macro applies a tabledesign to all tables in the document. Then it applies a paragraph format to the tables. When there are just a few tables (e.g. 20) this runs very slow.

How can I optimize it?

```
Sub Apply_tabledesign_to_all_tables()
'
' Apply_tabledesign_to_all_tables Macro
' Apply EVU table to all tables in document. 
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim ac_cell As Word.cell
        For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
            tbl.Style = "EVU"
        For Each ac_cell In tbl.Range.Cells
            ac_cell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("tabel")
        Next
        'Set the alignment for the first column
        For k = 1 To tbl.Columns(1).Cells.Count
                tbl.cell(k, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        Next k
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Edit: I forgot to include the alignment of the first column.

Comment: You're going cell to cell in table to table, why not just apply it to the entire table or the entire range? Two loops will always be slow

Comment: How do you define "very slow" precisely.

Comment: @Ramhound very slow: 15 minutes maybe? 14 pages 20 tables on an i7 with 16 gb ram?

Comment: @Raystafarian - okay - makes sense. I am not a VBA man yet, so most of the code is pieced together from googling. I actually tried to apply the paragraph style to the whole table - but without success. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit Excel? So 20 tables or 14 pages with 20 tables each?

Comment: @Ramhound word, not excel

Comment: @Raystafarian - The answer to my question would have answered if he has 64-bit version of Word installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping through tables and then looping through each cell in each table. That will take time. Address the range as a single object instead of looping through the cells.

Something like this should work (assuming your objects are correct)

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.Style = "EVU"
    tbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("tabel")
Next
End Sub
```

Essentially it's this (which does work for sure)

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.Style = "Light Shading"
    tbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.Style = "Heading 1"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that helped ALOT. Actually I have just updated my question as the last part is still tricky...

Comment: If this answers the question, please do not alter the question - instead ask a new one.

Comment: okay - do you think my update warrents another question? - it seems the answer is: apply you code to the highest object level possible (table not cell). - Just to make sure - I'll mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, so just apply to the entire range

Comment: It seems that it doesn't take loong to run through each cell after your optimization  - so this:  For k = 1 To tbl.Columns(1).Cells.Count
                tbl.cell(k, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        Next k
is still very fast. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another trick i had to implement is switching from page view to continuous view in order to block repagination. The point in this case is: word repaginate the whole document for every modification in tabs even if you stop screen updating.

My way to do have repagination effectively blocked is to save the current page view mode in a var an force continuous view just after screen updating blocking:

```
Dim ViewModeSave As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
ViewModeSave = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Type
Application.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Word.wdNormalView
```

At the end of the work, you have to take the original settings back:

```
Application.Options.Pagination = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ActiveWindow.View.Type = ViewModeSave
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, looping through cells in a table and setting the paragraph format of each cell. Although I agree with the answers above, it is not the looping through the cells that is the bottleneck, it is actually the paragraph formatting which is slow - incredibly slow. I experimented my altering the number of paragraph format properties I set in the loop. Setting 1 property was quick, but as I increased the number of properties I set to 8 the vba code became slower and slower; at 8 it was really slow. I think is just a word 2013 issue.

Comment: Even then: if one intends to format an entire table, then that's what one should do. Speed aside, this also allows Word to decide where to store the formatting information. Like, if badly implemented, then formatting each cell rather than the whole table might increase the file size.